# Pandas plot mean values from corresponding unique id values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

This is my csv file. I want to find the mean cost for each unique ids.

so for example: id 1, mean cost should be 20.

```
id,cost
1,10 
1,20
1,30
2,40
2,50
```

I got the output right with:

```
df.groupby(['id'])['cost'].mean()
id
1    20
2    45
Name: cost, dtype: int64
```

But i dont know how to plot such that x-axis is the id (1,2) and y axis as the mean values (20,45).

The below code made the mean to be the x-axis (should be on y-axis) while the y-axis is only until 1 (should be 2 and should be the x-axis).

```
df.groupby(['id'])['cost'].mean().hist()
```

[image]

Comment: You need a bar plot instead of histogram.

Comment: ah, makes sense since i already got the frequency. thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Piggybacking off of Psidom's comment...

```
df.groupby('id').mean().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

---

```
In [108]: df
Out[108]: 
   id  cost
0   1    10
1   1    20
2   1    30
3   2    40
4   2    50
```

Comment: assuming your df is not the original df?

Comment: Assuming my df is your df. Right?

Comment: oh got it, was wondering why you didn't need to specify the column 'cost'.